# puppetserver5.3.1 auth.conf Server Error: Not authorized to call search on /file_metadata/files

Tags: puppet

Error: /Stage[main]/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_files[lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar]/File[/mnt/wso2ei-6.1.1/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Not authorized to call search on /file_metadata/files/configs/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar with {:rest=>"files/configs/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar", :links=>"manage", :recurse=>true, :source_permissions=>"ignore", :checksum_type=>"md5"}
Error: /Stage[main]/Wso2base::Configure/Wso2base::Push_files[lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar]/File[/mnt/wso2ei-6.1.1/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///files/configs/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/files/configs/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar with {:rest=>"files/configs/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar", :links=>"manage", :checksum_type=>"md5", :source_permissions=>"ignore"}

Comment: How to enable the authorized, my auth.conf as below:
 {
            # Allow nodes to access all file_metadata.  Note that access for the
            # 'delete' method is forbidden by Puppet regardless of the
            # configuration of this rule.
            match-request: {
                path: "/puppet/v3/file_metadata"
                type: path
                method: [get, post]
            }
            allow: "*"
            sort-order: 500
            name: "puppetlabs file metadata"
        },

Comment: finally this is not a authorized issue, just the file got wrong name